# Alphanumeric Shellcode Ensuring Jumps

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I'm trying to write some shellcode that will eventually be in the form of an English paragraph.  This means that I'm mostly limited to instructions that have opcodes that evaluate to alphanumeric characters or punctuation.  This actually leaves me with many different jump instructions including: `jo`, `jno`, `jb`, `jae`, `je`, `jne`, `jbe`, `ja`, `js`, `jns`, and `jp` (which correspond to letters `p-z`).  Each of these jumps performs a test before it decides to jump or not.  In most cases I can combine a jump plus its inverse to ensure a jump will take place in the shellcode (e.g. using `jo` then `jno`, or `je` then `jne`), but I cannot do this in the case of `jb`.  The test for `jb` is `CF=1`.

My question is, is there any series of alphanumberic instructions that is functionally a NOP, but also ensures that `CF=1`?  `CF` is the carry flag, so any operations that are guaranteed to set the carry flag would suffice.

Also to ensure a `jae`, is the anyway to ensure that the `CF=0`?

Comment: Great question. I don't really see a solution to this, but I'm really looking forward to any developments. `STC` would be perfect here, but it's `F9`, which doesn't have anything to do with ASCII.

Comment: The eventual goal of this is English shellcode, so shellcode using letters, numbers, and punctuation is what I'm working with.  The most useful though are English words or common English digraphs or trigraphs that can be put within other code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **"4444"** to set `CF` to 0.

**"44"** is `XOR AL, 0x34`.

2 `XORs` with the same value result no change in `AL`.

It should be noted, though, that `XOR` affects almost all arithmetic flags (effect on `AF` is undefined). So, it's not completely "NOP".

In 32-bit mode you can use **"PhohohX7X"** to set `CF` to 1.

**"P"** is `PUSH EAX`.
**"hohoh"** is `PUSH 0x686F686F`.
**"X"** is `POP EAX`.
**"7"** is `AAA`.
**"X"** is `POP EAX`.

There's a caveat with `AAA`, too. Its effect on most of arithmetic flags is undefined (`CF` and `AF` excepted, they become equal). So, it's not completely "NOP" either.

Comment: What is the nature of XOR and AAA's affect on CF?  Do they always set it to 0 and 1 respectively?

Comment: XOR - always. AAA - no (if it had, I wouldn't have used PUSH and POP and some "magic" 0x686F686F value). See the CPU manual (from Intel or AMD) for details of their operation.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful conceptually.  Eventually I want my shellcode to be English paragraphs, so opcodes that are statistically probably alphanumeric digraphs or words would be most convenient, though.  This helped a lot though.

Comment: Also, `AAA` is not available in 64-bit mode. :(

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: which is why I wrote "In 32-bit mode...". `IMUL` can be used to set CF=1.

Comment: @cytinus: Did I not give you two sequences to set `CF` to 0 and 1? You want more? You asked for any.

Comment: You did, but while 4444 and PhohohX7X, are alphanumeric, they are less useful in creating English shellcode.  PhohohX7X is not a subset of any word or sentence, and 4444 is a very specific number.  I was looking for something more along the lines of a common English digraph or trigraph, or something that was more easily combined into words.

Comment: Yes I did ask for alphanumeric.  But I want it to not only be alphanumeric, but alphanumeric and potentially expandable into proper English shellcode.  This means using only valid English words and grammar.  This means that anything I use must be an alphanumeric subset of a possible valid English word or sentence.